# Permuting tensor indices and relations to rearranging factors in a general-size kronecker product operators on same space?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, kronecker-product, vectorization, similar-matrices

Given the [following conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427421/can-permutation-similarities-change-order-of-kronecker-products/3430836#3430836), we can start considering larger than $2$ factor Kronecker products.

Let us say we define:

$$R_1\otimes R_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes R_N$$

And then the operation "permute" $P_{k,l}\{m\}$ :

$$P_{k,l}\{R_1\otimes \cdots  R_k \cdots R_l  \cdots \otimes R_N\} = P_{k,l}\{R_1\otimes \cdots  R_l \cdots R_k  \cdots \otimes R_N\} $$

In other words, changing place of only factor number $k$ and $l$ and everything else remains in place.

Would a matrix representation of this permute for the vectorization of an $N$-dimensional tensor also work to change indices $k$ and $l$ in vectorization of said tensor?

The special case in the link above hints that the answer is affirmative for permuting index 1 and 2 in a 2 dimensional tensor up to kronecker product sizes $(9\times 9)\otimes(9 \times 9)$ corresponding to operators on a $9 \times 9$ sized tensor space. But this is just a very tiny special case. The really interesting ones for my purposes is for example separable transforms in image-processing where at least the first two indices can take thousands of values and dimensionality can be $4$ or even $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer but maybe a hint in the right direction:

First of all, you need to be able to shuffle rows *and* columns. The way you write it, you only shuffle as both your P's operate on rows. You'll need some kind of $$(R_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes R_N) \cdot P_1 = P_2 \cdot (R_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes R_N).$$ If you allow for this, I think it should be possible. I've studied something related, since I was interested in cyclic permutations of Kronecker products. One can show that you can find permutations such that  $$(R_1 \otimes R_2 \ldots \otimes R_N) \cdot P_1 = P_2 \cdot (R_2 \otimes \ldots \otimes R_N \otimes R_1).$$ The way I constructed these is a little backwards as I began by defining permutations for different unfoldings of multi-way matrices and then used these to construct the permutations you see up there. What was helpful for me was to define a product $\boxtimes$ that's like a Kronecker product with with a different column ordering, namely $A \boxtimes B = [A \otimes b_1, \ldots, A \otimes b_N]$, where $b_n$ are the columns of $B$. With this you can write the commutation matrices $K_{m,n}$ as $K_{m,n} = I_m \boxtimes I_n$. I used this formalism to define $R$-D permutations $$P_{M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_R}^{(r)} = (I_{M_R} \boxtimes \ldots \boxtimes I_{M_{r+1}}) \otimes (I_{M_{r-1}} \boxtimes \ldots \boxtimes I_{M_1}).$$ Once you have these in place, you can show that $$(R_1 \otimes R_2 \ldots \otimes R_N) \cdot P_1 = P_2 \cdot (R_2 \otimes \ldots \otimes R_N \otimes R_1)$$ if $P_1 = P_{M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_R}^{(R)^{\rm T}}P_{M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_R}^{(1)}$ and $P_2 = P_{N_1,N_2,\ldots,N_R}^{(R)^{\rm T}}P_{N_1,N_2,\ldots,N_R}^{(1)}$ for $R_n$ is $M_n \times N_n$.

Not the most elegant way of doing things, I know. And it doesn't directly solve your problem. But you might think about going along this path. If you're interested in more details check out Appendix B.3 and B.7 of my [dissertation](https://theses.eurasip.org/theses/473/advanced-algebraic-concepts-for-efficient-multi/download/) (sorry for the shameless self-advertising but I really didn't find any publication that discusses this).